# R how to "split" on combined subsets?

Tags: r, split, subset

Let's say I have a factor that has a bunch of levels in it.  And I have grouped some of those levels as represented by the grps variable.

I can use "split" to split my data frame, but is it possible to split the data frame so that the combined levels represented by grps are in the same split?

```
set.seed(42)
fooLevels <- c(115,119,156,120,158,219)
foo <- fooLevels[round(runif(20, min=1, max=6))]
doo <- rnorm(20)
df <- data.frame(foo,doo)

grps <- c("{115}","{119}","{156}{120}{158}{219}")
splits <- split(df, f = df$foo)
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
>splits
$`{115}`
   foo         doo
8  115  0.08983289
9  115 -2.99309008
12 115  0.18523056

$`{119}`
   foo        doo
2  119 -0.7838389
7  119  0.6792888
13 119  0.5818237

$`{156}{120}{158}{219}`
   foo        doo
1  120  0.3219253
4  120  0.6428993
6  120  0.2765507
11 120 -0.3672346
18 120  1.0385061
20 120  0.7208782
3  156 1.5757275
10 156 0.2848830
17 156 0.3358481
5  158 0.08976065
16 158 1.30254263
19 158 0.92072857
14 219  1.3997368
15 219 -0.7272921
```

The order of the rows in the list(data.frame) is of no consequence.

Comment: Is your `grps` object something that already exists (with those curly brackets and so on) or do you have the relevant values stored in some other way?

Comment: Yes, it already exists like that.  I can change it to store the values another, more meaningful way if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the names of the list and change the expression in `str_split` to whatever works for you.

```
lapply(
    strsplit(
        grps, 
        '}\\{|\\{|}'
    ), 
    function(x) {
        df[df$foo %in% x,]
    }
)
[[1]]
[1] foo doo
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]
   foo       doo
3  119 -1.388861
8  119 -2.656455
14 119  1.214675
18 119 -1.763163

[[3]]
   foo        doo
1  219  1.3048697
2  219  2.2866454
4  158 -0.2787888
5  120 -0.1333213
6  120  0.6359504
7  158 -0.2842529
9  120 -2.4404669
10 158  1.3201133
11 156 -0.3066386
12 158 -1.7813084
13 219 -0.1719174
15 156  1.8951935
16 219 -0.4304691
17 219 -0.2572694
19 156  0.4600974
20 120 -0.6399949
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `grp` object does not already exist, you could do something like this

```
x = split(df, df$foo)
y = Reduce(`rbind`, x[names(x)> 120])
o = c(x[names(x) <= 120], setNames(list(y), paste(unique(y$foo), collapse = ' ')))

#> o
#$`119`
#   foo       doo
#3  119 -1.388861
#8  119 -2.656455
#14 119  1.214675
#18 119 -1.763163

#$`120`
#   foo        doo
#5  120 -0.1333213
#6  120  0.6359504
#9  120 -2.4404669
#20 120 -0.6399949

#$`156 158 219`
#   foo        doo
#11 156 -0.3066386
#15 156  1.8951935
#19 156  0.4600974
#4  158 -0.2787888
#7  158 -0.2842529
#10 158  1.3201133
#12 158 -1.7813084
#1  219  1.3048697
#2  219  2.2866454
#13 219 -0.1719174
#16 219 -0.4304691
#17 219 -0.2572694
```